# Is there any way we can access localStorage and stored cookie and pathname in next js server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wanted to use either localStorage or cookies in SSR of next js. as window object is not available in SSR how I can access it?

Comment: window object available in `componentDidMount`, componentDidMount  is React implementation and it's always triggered on the Browser.

Comment: You can access request object in `getInitialProps` on server.  So you could access cookies. Definitely not `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

For using cookies on both server and client, this package is really convenient: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-cookies

Comment: this library does not have an option to create cookie, just to read its value

Comment: cookie-universal-nuxt is capable of both reading and creating cookies